# Issues with TimeStamp precision at RESTful services

Tags: java, postgresql, rest

I am working with some data on `postgreSQL` and I am fetching them using `JPA` specifications. When displaying them in Angular `front-end` I can already see that the date is missing precision, namely from `2018-01-26 11:48:07.13487` it is something like `2018-01-26 11:48:07.134`, that is it is missing 2 digits of precision. Now the problem is that this column is part of the `primary key` so that I cannot work on operations like `put` later on because the date won't match. 
 
The problem is really happening at the REST services. If I print the data on eclipse the date precision appears totally fine but then when I check them at REST it has lost 2 digits of precision `2018-01-26T10:48:07.134+0000`.
Conversely, I can try to fix the precision on the front-end (that is, `2018-01-26 11:48:07.13487`) and then issue a `put` request. On the back-end I can notice that it looses the precision and goes back to `2018-01-26 11:48:07.134`.

I  am testing on very simple `REST`ful services like for instance:

```
@GetMapping("/getAllData")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<StammSolvaraJahr> getAllData() {
    EntityManager em = Connection.getEntityManger();
    return em.createQuery("SELECT ssj FROM StammSolvaraJahr ssj").setMaxResults(100).getResultList();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why using timestamps as keys is discouraged, same reason for floating point types. Note that JSON does not define a specific representation for dates/times and thus no precision/resolution which must be supported. So you're bound to get into trouble if you rely on it. An option may be to send the timestamp with e.g. seconds resolution in one field and the fractionals (e.g. in nanoseconds) in another integer field.

Comment: What is imprecise about a timestamp? It is an integer. OP's problem must be that the values are mutilated somewhere along the way.

Comment: "a timestamp [...] is an integer." - Do you have any source backing up that claim? Especially, any canonical definition for how a timestamp is represented as an integer?

Comment: Sorry, I was too short. `include/datatype/timestamp.h` has: `typedef int64 TimestampTz;`. It used to be a floating point value some time ago though.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So *some* C library on *some* platform has *one* representation of *some* kind of timestamp as int64. How does that relate to the original question which has absolutely nothing to do with C?

Comment: Again I was not clear enough :^( That is not some library, that is PostgreSQL's source. And the question is about PostgreSQL, isn't it? My point is that there are no rounding errors with timestamps *in PostgreSQL* like there are with converting IEEE floating point numbers to strings. That's why the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I'm beginning to see the relevance ;-) I don't doubt that PostgreSql does not cause loss of precision for either floating point nor timestamp types. But both timestamps and FPs are in most cases converted during processing (e.g. to strings, or platform specific date/time types). And while for FPs there are the IEE standard types with defined precision and representation, the precision of timestamps varies between applications which is why they don't make good key candidates.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, just wanted to point out that it does not apply to PostgreSQL.

Comment: True. I thought it was obvious that the DB is not to blame here; probably should've made that more clear.

Comment: I have two more questions. First what would be the best approach to send the timestamp with seconds and nanoseconds? In the abovementioned code example I am returning a list of objects. Should I just add two more fields to the object for this purpose? Then, in order to do this I would need to iterate the whole list which would have tens of thousands of records. Would this be feasible?

Comment: You have several options. Note that it is considered a best practice to separate entities and corresponding [data transfer objects (DTOs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object); the DTOs are used to transfer the entities' data across e.g. the network instead of the entities themselves. One of the reasons is that entities may require certain structure and attributes which should be different for transfer than for DB access. In your case, you could/should create a `StammSolvaraJahrDTO` class, plus possibly dependent classes, and map (copy) between entities and DTOs in your service.

Comment: Then you can map the entity's timestamp field to one or more DTO fields as you need. This shouldn't be much overhead, even for "tens of thousands" of objects.

Comment: @Bendemann Btw, what's the data type for the timestamp in `StammSolvaraJahr`? If it's `java.util.Date` then you already lose the precision when loading records, because `Date` only has milliseconds resolution. Try `java.time.Instant` (requires a custom JPA [`AttributeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html)), or maybe `java.sql.Timestamp` (nanoseconds precision) directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look it up. Yeah the datatype is a timestamp but as you noticed in the original answer, the precision is being lost because of jSon conversion, that is when I am reading it from the database using JPA it is fine but after transfering with jSon it is losing precision.